# Using jquery remove() with id passed by variable. Possible?

Tags: php, jquery, dom, asynchronous

This is the function

```
function deleteItem(id) {
    $.post("_asyncpage.php",
        {id:id},
        function (result) {
            if (result == true) {
                $('#'+id).remove();
            }
        }, "json"); 
}
```

So, to explain, the function receive an id, send to a page that execute random stuff on a db and return true/false.

The function inside check for result that can be true/false as said before.
If true proceed to remove the dom element that match the id passed.

The db is updated correctly but the .remove() won't work... someone knows why? :(

The following is an example of the html structure. the table inside the TD is the one to be deleted.

```
<td width="120" valign="top" id="13_02">
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tableProg" id="1">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3"><h4 style="margin: 0pt;">Title</h4></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3">h. 13:35</td></tr><tr><td width="74"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(0, 102, 204);">Su</span>: TV</td>
         <td width="22"><a href="javascript:openEditItem('2010/08/24','1')"><img src="static/images/edit.gif"></a></td>
         <td width="22"><a href="javascript:deleteItem('1')"><img src="static/images/delete.gif"></a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the `id` you're passing, as well as the `result` response?

Comment: id is always a number (of course is passed as string via paramter).
result is always true/false boolean type.

I've checked that the function go through the if but not execute the remove().

Comment: An ID can not start with a number in HTML4. It is not valid.

Comment: Oooh, i was supposing the problem was the number.
Thank you for your hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** From the additional info you provided, the issue may be with your IDs. It is not valid for an ID to start with a number. This can cause problems.

---

<s>If your `id` that you're passing to the function already has a `#` at the beginning, then you don't want to concatenate it.</s>

Also, if the response you're getting is a string, then you would want to compare the result to the string `'true'`.

```
if (result == 'true') {...
```

Comment: very unlikely that `result` contains a string, if it's a `json string` like it should be.

Comment: The function $.post has been called with the attribute ("json") that means it parse the result as a jsonObject so true/false has been automatically converted into boolean from string. I'm saying crap stuff?

Comment: While i'll try another solution i'm agree with you. I wish to have more reputation to give you a vote :(
Hope my gratitude will be enough :)

Comment: @theCrius - That's plenty. :o)

Comment: @theCrius - By the way, what @James Wiseman was saying was to test the `length` property of the jQuery object. This will tell you how many matches were found. If `$('#'+id).length` gives you `0`, then you know there was no match.

Comment: Yep, i had understand it and that was very smart ;)
i'm *saved* this procedure for the next time i got problem with js :)

Answer (score 0):

I would inspect your `result`. Do you return `true` as number (1)? or is it a string when received?

Since you're dataType is `json`, the value of `result` must be a `json string` or an already parsed `object`, so I bet pretty much that this

```
if (result == true) {
```

will never pass.

Comment: I'll pass true/false as a string (output in page from the asyncpage.php) but i supposed that the operator "==" would pass for every value equal to false as 0, '', null, etc.

Anyway i'll try with:
if (result == 'true')
Thanks for the celerity of the suggest :)

Comment: Oki, that was not the problem.
Using a simple alert i've checked that the process enter the if but simply not execute the jquery command.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `$('#'+id).remove();` getting executed?

What happens if you do `alert($('#'+id).length)`? You should expect an answer > 0

Also, what is the type of `result`? Try `alert(typeof(result));` This will help you determine the correct comparison for your  `if` check

Comment: Oki, the result is 'boolean'.
The lenght of the id is 1 at the moment.

id will be always a number (corrispond to the id of the record into the database) and it's the id of a table created inside a table.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give more info, this is a portion of the structure that need to be removed via jquery.

```
<td width="120" valign="top" id="13_02">
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tableProg" id="1">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3"><h4 style="margin: 0pt;">Title</h4></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3">h. 13:35</td></tr><tr><td width="74"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(0, 102, 204);">Su</span>: TV</td>
         <td width="22"><a href="javascript:openEditItem('2010/08/24','1')"><img src="static/images/edit.gif"></a></td>
         <td width="22"><a href="javascript:deleteItem('1')"><img src="static/images/delete.gif"></a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
</td>
```

Comment: Please post additional information in your question instead of in an answer. I'll transfer this information. Please see the update in my answer.